# Applying the Simplex method with a known LHS?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, simplex

Im curious whether or not it’s possible to apply the Simplex method to an equation where the LHS (which we’re typically trying to maximise or minimise) is already a known value.

For example given a simple equation such as $10 = 2x + 2y$, with potentially some constraints on $x$ and $y$. Could I still apply the Simplex algorithm to find values for $x$ and $y$?

If so, how would I represent the LHS in the tableaux?

Comment: Perhaps you can form a different LP problem with the given equation as a constraint?

Comment: Do you mean that you're just trying to find some solution to a system of inequalities?